# $x_{n+1}=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}a_{(n,k)}x_k $, $S=\{x_1,x_2,...\}$ is finite then $0 \in S$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $ (R,+,\cdot) $ be a ring. Let $M=\{x_1,x_2,...,x_m\}$ a set of elements from $R$.

Consider the following numbers:

$$x_{n+1}=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\binom{n}{k}x_k $$
for every $n\ge m$

**Conjecture**:

> Prove that if $S=\{x_1,x_2,...\}$ is finite then $$0 \in S$$

I was wondering if this is true.

If it is true then:

> If it is so, I might be curious in proving the same result but instead
> the condition
>
> $$x_{n+1}=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\binom{n}{k}x_k $$ for every $n\ge m$
>
> to have
>
> $$x_{n+1}=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}a_{(n,k)}x_k $$ for every $n\ge m$
>
> where $a{(n,k)}$ are some arbitrary elements from $R$.

I would highly appreciate if everyone would contribute with something no matter how insignificant so as to find an answer to this conjecture.

Comment: Is the ring assumed to be commutative?

Comment: No, it isn't commutative

Comment: Can you please say from where you have got these type of  questions?