# $c_n=a^n-b^n$, $S=\{c_1,c_2,...\}$ is finite then $0 \in S$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Statement:

> Let $  (R,+,\cdot)  $ be a ring that has at least two invertible
> elements. Let $a,b$ be two invertible elements such that
> $$ord(a)=ord(b)=+\infty$$ Let consider the following sequence
> $$c_n=a^n-b^n$$  Let $S=\{c_1,c_2,...,c_m,...\}$ a set of elements
> from $R$.
>
> Prove that if $S=\{c_1,c_2,...\}$ is finite then $$0 \in S$$

Attempt:

I obtained that:

$$a^n-b^n=c_n$$
then $$a^{n+1}-ab^n=ac_n$$
and $$a^{n+1}-b^{n+1}=c_{n+1}$$
then
$$(b-a)b^{n}=ac_n-c_{n+1}$$
Since $S$ is finite then $$M=\{ac_n-c_{n+1},n \in \mathbb Z_+\}$$ is finite.

So $$\{(b-a)b^n,n \in \mathbb Z_+\}$$ is finite.
Then there exists $i$ and $j$ such that $$(b-a)b^i=(b-a)b^j$$

How should I continue with this. I would highly appreciate somebody's help.

Comment: Is there a connection to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4450290/x-n1-sum-k-1n-1a-n-kx-k-s-x-1-x-2-is-finite-then-0) you had before?

Comment: Is the ring assumed to be commutative?

Comment: No, the ring is not commutative.

Answer (score 2):

**Modified to NOT assume $R$ is commutative**

Continuing from where you left off, you could use your line of reasoning to show the following: For *any* positive integer $l$ [not just $l=1$], there is a *positive* integer $k_l$ such that
$$(a^{k_l}-1)c_l = 0.$$
[Indeed for each such $l$ there exists distinct integers $i$ and $j$ such that $a^ic_l = a^jc_l$, and assume $j >i$. Then $k_l=j-i$ works.] Furthermore, $(a^k-1)c_l =0$ for any $k$ that is a *multiple* of $k_l$, because even in a noncommutative ring, $(a^{C_1}-1)$ and $(a^{C_2}-1)$ commute for any two integers $C_1$,$C_2$. So let $T$ be a *finite* set of integers $l$ such that for all $m \in \mathbb{N}$ there is an $l \in T$ such that $c_m=c_l$, and set
$$k = \prod_{l \in T} k_l.$$
Then
$$(a^k-1)c_m = 0 \ \forall m \in \mathbb{N}.$$

In fact, for any multiple $K$ of $k$, it follows that
$$(a^K-1)c_m =0 \ \forall m \in \mathbb{N}.$$ Thus we conclude with the following:

**Claim 1** *There is a positive integer $k \in \mathbb{N}$ such that the equation $$(a^K-1)c_m=0 \ \forall m \in \mathbb{N}$$ holds for all multiples $K$ of $k$.*

We also make the following claim:

**Claim 2** *There exists a multiple $K$ of $k$ and a positive integer $n$ such that the equation $c_{n+K}=c_n$ holds.*

Proof: Let $N$ be the number of distinct $c_l$; $l \in \mathbb{N}$. Then for any positive integer $m$, at least two of $c_m, c_{m+jk}$; $j=1,2,\ldots, N$; must be the same by the Pigeonhole Principle. ■

So, using Claims 1 and 2, let $K$ be a multiple of $k$, where $k$ is as in Claim 1, and let $n$ be an integer such that the equation $c_n=c_{n+K}$ holds.

Then simple algebra gives
$$a^Kc_n +a^Kb^n -b^{n+K} = c_{n+K}.$$
plugging into this the equation $c_n=c_{n+K}$ and rearranging gives
$$(a^K-1)c_{n+K} + c_Kb^n = 0.$$
But, as $K$ is a multiple of $k$ as in Claim 1, the equation $(a^K-1)c_{n+K}=0$ holds, so we are left with the equation
$$c_Kb^n = 0.$$
As $b^n$ is invertible, it follows that the equation $$c_K=0$$ must hold. ■

Comment: For the equation
$$
a^Kc_n +a^Kb^n -b^{n+K} = c_{n+K}
$$
can you provide a little more detail?

Comment: $$a^Kc_n +a^Kb^n-b^{n+K}$$ $$= a^K(a^n-b^n)+a^Kb^n-b^{n+k}$$ $$= (a^{K+n}-a^Kb^n)+a^kb^n-b^{n+K}$$ $$=a^{K+n}  -a^Kb^n+a^kb^n -b^{n+K}$$ $$=a^{n+K}-b^{n+K}$$ $$= c_{n+K}$$.

Comment: @quasi here it is in the above comment

Comment: Got it. Thanks.${}{}{}{}{}{}{}$